# Erros Script C# Unity3D 5.2.0f3! Erros com o RigidBody2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-2015

Estou com um problema em um código C# que estou utilizando para fazer um jogo no Unity3D Versão 5.2.0f3

Este Código eu peguei em um [video do Jogando com Nils](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmA0paVG16g) ( Canal do Youtube que ensina a desenvolver jogos.

Esta me acontecendo um erro na hora de setar os Comandos do player, principalmente agora que o unity3d atualizou e esta utilizando o Visual Studio 2015 (Não sei mexer nele).

Após eu criar um código em C# para utilizar em meu player, me apresentou os seguintes erros:

[image: Este é o VS com o codigo aberto]

Este é o Código :

```
using UnityEngine; // Obrigado por avisar desta linha gamesinsanity
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
// The force which is added when the player jumps
// This can be changed in the Inspector window
public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 280);

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Jump
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
    {
        Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        Rigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpForce);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: O erro é auto-descritivo mas para dar uma solução precisaria ver outros trechos do código. Talvez vendo o vídeo a gente consigo ajudar mas seria complicado a gente ter que vê-lo para resolver seu problema. Provavelmente você teria que estar usando uma variável com uma instância de um objeto no lugar de `Rigidbody2D` que é um tipo. Mas não posso afirmar sem ver mais contexto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consigo ver a imagem do erro mas uma coisa que está errada e posso apontar vendo o código é a forma de acessar o componente Rigidbody2D. A Unity 5 ajustou sua sintaxe para alinhar melhor com os conceitos de escopo e visibilidade do C# (propriamente orientado à objetos) então onde antes você acessaria os componentes do seu GameObject como atributos agora você precisa acessar com os métodos GetComponent() ou GetComponents(). Você pode encontrar mais informações de como utilizar corretamente o acesso aos componentes na documentação ([videos](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/getcomponent) e [referências](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html))

Resumidamente, se você tem o Rigidbody2D anexado ao mesmo objeto que seu script você pode simplesmente substituir a chamada `Rigidbody2D` por `GetComponent<RigidBody2D>()`. Mas eu aconselho a dar uma olhada na documentação para entender o correto uso deste método até para evitar problemas de desempenho uma vez que ele faz uma busca e não um acesso direto ao componente convém você guardar uma referência em seu script ao invés de realizar a busca toda vez que precisar utilizar.

Caso este componente esteja em um objeto parente ou filho do objeto onde está o script a forma de acessar vai mudar ou até mesmo o método de busca por isso é importante olhar a documentação e entender o que está sendo feito ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Comment: Bruno note que na resposta original o método ficou sem a tipagem porque eu não tinha colocado no bloco de código, já editei e ajustei. É necessário passar o tipo que vc quer encontrar no método entre <>

Answer (score 1):

Vc está tentando acessar a Classe Objeto e não o objeto criado em memória para ser usado.
Para usar um objeto do tipo rigidbody2D, vc precisar ter ele em algum lugar como referencia, eu aconselho a fazer desta maneira.

Primeiro crie um objeto Rigidbody2D, depois no Start* eu pego a referencia dele que já existe no objeto criado, e dentro do Update eu uso o objeto que eu criei que tem a referencia ao Rigidbody2D.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 280);
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

    void Start()
    {
         this.rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
       // Jump
       if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
       {
           this.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
           this.rigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpForce);
       }
    }
}
```